# get_option() not returning expected value from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, include, options

I am trying to make my first plugin, and so far everything has been fine except one little annoying thing.  I have my fields setup and updating data and looks just fine in my database:

```
mfwp_settings | a:1:{i:test;s:3:"response";}
```

But when I want to echo the value for 'test' in my Admin Panel it comes back blank or NULL.  It echos fine on a front end page but within the the plugin it wont retrieve the data using the following:

```
$mfwp_opt = get_option('mfwp_settings')['test'];
```

Again, the above fires fine in a normal php on the front end.  So I can only assume the problem is with a missing 'path' and/or 'includes' on the Plugin's main PHP.

**So.... is there a special path I need to put into the main plugin PHP?**

I put in an ABPATH just in case that was it, but no luck:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}
```

I've thought that I could copy and adjust the 'get_option' function and use it in my own plugin, but that seems unnecessary.  So any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**

So to be more clear I've put the php I'm working below. Everything about the php works fine EXCEPT it will not call the `get_option` or retrieve the data through `$wpdb`.

```
<?php
// Initiate Global(s)
global $wpdb;
//TRIED to call normally via get_option, but it wouldn't fire
$test = get_option( 'mfwp_settings' );
//TRIED to call via SQL, but comes back as NULL
$get_settings = $wpdb->get_results ( "
        SELECT * 
        FROM $wpdb->wp_options
        WHERE option_name = mfwp_settings
        LIMIT 1
        " );
$field1 = get_option( mfwp_settings );
// Creating Admin Menu option
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
    add_options_page(
            //CHANGE
            'My First Wordpress Plugin', //title browser
            //CHANGE
            'MFWP', //menu text
            //KEEP
            'manage_options', //require capability **KEEP AS manage_options**
            //CHANGE
            'mfwp_admin', //reference slug
            //CHANGE
            'mfwp_options_page' //callback to menu body
            );
}
);
// Call Back & create body - CHANGE prefix
function mfwp_options_page() {
    //ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>My First WordPress Plugin Options</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                settings_fields( 'mfwp_settings_group' );
            ?>
            <h4><?php _e('Placeholder for Plugin Fields', 'mfwp_domain'); ?></h4>
            <p><?php echo $field1 . ' tester<br />'; echo var_dump($get_settings);?>
                <label class="description" for="mfwp_settings"><?php _e('This is a label description', 'mfwp_domain'); ?></label>
                <input class="regular-text" id="mfwp_settings" name="mfwp_settings" type="" value="<?php echo $test; ?>"> 
            </p>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Option', 'mfwp_domain'); ?>">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    //echo ob_get_clean();
}
function mfwp_register_settings() {
        $args = array(
            'type' => 'string', 
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field', //Sanatizes data
            'default' => NULL,
            );
    register_setting('mfwp_settings_group', 'mfwp_settings', $args);
}
add_action('admin_init', 'mfwp_register_settings');
```

Comment: So to be more clear I've put the php I'm working on into a Gist:
[link](https://gist.github.com/yellowstonebum/543008819e3a8c372e7c1649a385051a)

 Everything about the php works fine EXCEPT it will not call the get_option or retrieve the data through $wpdb.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your serialized settings are corrupted. I created the option `mfwp_settings` with the value `array( 'test' => 'response' )`. When I look at this in the database, the value is stored as a serialized array and looks like this:

> ```
> a:1:{s:4:"test";s:8:"response";}
> ```

Here is a simple debugging function that successfully returns the expected value `response` for `test`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_option_test' );
function wpse_option_test() {

    // Example data. Serialized, it will look like this: a:1:{s:4:"test";s:8:"response";}
    $settings_value = array( 'test' => 'response' );

    add_option( 'mfwp_settings' );
    update_option( 'mfwp_settings', $settings_value );
    $mfwp_settings = get_option( 'mfwp_settings' )['test'];

    // Output the value for debugging. Result: string(8) "response"
    exit ( var_dump( $mfwp_settings ) );
}
```

Comment: Didn't work quite right, but the Serializing is definitely a good point.  I messed with my "register_setting" to look more like this:function mfwp_register_settings() {
     $args = array(
            'type' => 'string', 
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            'default' => NULL,
            );
 register_setting('mfwp_settings_group', 'mfwp_settings', $args);
}
add_action('admin_init', 'mfwp_register_settings');

But it still isn't firing... I also tried to call it using $wpdb and it's not querying...

Comment: I think there's some missing info here. Please [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/323230/edit) your original question and include all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue. There's definitely something fishy with the way your data is stored. I'd suggest deleting the `mfwp_settings` option in the DB and starting fresh. Consider using the [Custom Settings Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/) example from the docs as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've added a comment to the original with a gist leading to the document I'm working on: [link](https://gist.github.com/yellowstonebum/543008819e3a8c372e7c1649a385051a)

Comment: Taking a look over the code. You should use `$test = get_option( 'mfwp_settings' );` to get *all* of the options stored for `mfwp_settings`. You should not be using `$wpdb` to get settings stored using the settings API. Again, [start with the example from the handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/). It works. Then, tweak it to fit your needs. Quick note --in the future, please paste any relevant code directly into the question. You can always edit your original question to add updates, etc.